# File in use C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file

I'm learning C/C++ right now and I am reading about file operations. Suppose a program A is working with an external file (say, a text file) and another another program B is, say, trying to move the file (or worse, delete it). Is it possible to tell the OS to inform the program B that the file is in use, even though it was not created by program A?

Comment: What OS are you using? Some filesystems support file locking, some don't. It depends.

Comment: @Chris I'm using Win 7 but I also have a Ubuntu 10 partition so I want to program for both.

Comment: @Fred The book I'm reading is about C++ but some of the first chapters are on C as a foundation for C++. According to the book, C is still in good use for system and hardware programming.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with C, and C and C++ are definitely related. But they are different languages with distinctly different cultures and idioms. An answer that is appropriate for one may not be appropriate for the other. There's no such language as "C/C++".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking). Search for "file locking in C".

Comment: Thanx. Just checked the link. Is there any link on writing the code in C++ or C (Windows and Linux)?

Comment: Sure is. But it depends on your operating system. Read the article and you'll find references to the functions you can use both on Windows and on UNIX systems. When you find the function you're looking for, look for tutorials about using it. If you can't find any good tutorial about it and you can't manage to make it work, you can ask a specific question about it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A file is a resource.

If you happen to `open` one in C/C++, or any other language for that matter, the OS "lends" this file to your program. While you have control of a file (resource) the OS prevents other processes from taking control over it (i.e. moving the file, deleting the file, etc.).

This is why it's important to `close` a file after you're done working with it. This tells the OS that you no longer control this resource and other processes can fully access them.

Comment: -1. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking: "UNIX does not automatically lock open files and programs".